# How to start a Journey based on linked knowledge article in Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, case

I want to start a journey based on the knowledge article that's attached to an case in Saleforce.
In journey builder i can't select de CaseArticle object in filtercriteria (or entry source).

Does someone has an idea how to achieve this?

Kind regards,

Daniel

Comment: Can you flag a field in an object related to the Case that is available to select as a SF Data source in the JB entry event? Do you need to include a link to the PDF in the email?

Comment: The knowledge article doesn't have to be available in the journey to the customer. It must serve as a trigger (entry criteria) (or a filter criteria) to start the journey.

I can use an other field/event to trigger the journey, but that's only if the 'knowledge option' can't.